Is it "ok" to see constants as a "section" in $n$ dimentional space to get to lower dimentionality space?
Given that in $y=5x$, $5$ is a constant (let's call it $a=5$) in a 2d graph.
I thought that it could be seen as a simplification of a more general case of some 3d space where $y$ is a function of both $x$ and $a$. Thus saying $y=5x$ is like taking a plane and cutting the 3d graph while $a=5$.
Question:
Isn't saying 'constants equal slicing to get lower dimensionality' an oversimplification of the concept? And does it always "hold water"?
For instance, is it true that $y=5x+6$ is a 2-d slice of a 4d space with 2 constants where $y$ is a function of $a$, $x$, and $b$ (while $a=5$, $b=6$)?
Thanks.

Could you put some dollar signs around expressions? For example, $y=5x+6$ ($y=5x+6$) looks much nicer.

In highschool mathematics you learn that there are "variables", such as $x, y, z, t$, "parameters", such as $a, b, p, q$ and "constants" such as $\pi$, $e$ and $\sqrt{2}$. But actually the distinction is rather arbitrary. A parameter can at any time be set to a fixed value, and then it becomes a constant. But one may also perform operations on a parameter, such as differentiation. The parameter then behaves just like a variable. Similarly a variable can obtain a fixed value in a mathematical problem, after which it behaves like a parameter or a constant. It all depends on the mathematical problem at hand, and on the personal style of the mathematician.
So you start with the equation $y=5x$, and then propose to write this as $y = ax$ where $a=5$. That is perfectly fine ! You can also omit the last condition on $a$, so that for the moment it remains a free parameter. You are then indeed working in a $3D$ space $(x,y,a)$. Later on you can still impose the condition $a=5$.
